# Directory path and URL

Tags: java, path, directory, jetty

I'm having difficulty figuring out how the directory path works for this jetty HTTP server. I've tried http://localhost:8080/test in a browser which doesn't list the directory files as expected (a C:\test directory exists). Am i at least using the correct path for the directory i'm trying to use? Is the browser URL i'm attempting correct?

```
Server server = new Server();
SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
connector.setPort(8080);
server.addConnector(connector);

ResourceHandler resourceHandle = new ResourceHandler();
resourceHandle.setDirectoriesListed(true);
ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });

resource_handler.setResourceBase("/test");


System.out.println("resourcebase: " + resource_handler.getResourceBase()); //not working

HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resource_handler, new DefaultHandler() });
server.setHandler(handlers);

server.start();
server.join();
```

Edit: print is not even working and no exceptions caught

```
try {
      startFileHTTP();
} catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("HTTP error");
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is at

```
resource_handler.setResourceBase("/test");
```

Are you sure that the base path is `C:\`?